# MySQL + VB.NET - Populate multiple Datagridviews from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a Form with a TabControl with 8 tabs, each tab have a Datagridview that needs to be populated each one from a different table of my database. I'd like to know if i need to make all the 8 connections and queries or i can apply the DRY principle and how i can do it.

Actually I'm trying populate the Datagridviews but I don't know why I'm just getting populated 3 of them and the rest just stay empty.

I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class frmMantenimiento
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataEmp As New DataTable
    Dim dataNomi As New DataTable
    Dim dataPres As New DataTable
    Dim dataGast As New DataTable
    Dim dataAmon As New DataTable
    Dim dataHora As New DataTable
    Dim SQL As String

    Public Sub FillEmps()
        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = "SELECT IDEmpleado as ID, Nombre, Cargo FROM Empleados"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataEmp)

                dgvConsEmp.DataSource = dataEmp

                dgvConsEmp.Columns(0).Width = 30
                dgvConsEmp.Columns(1).Width = 200
                dgvConsEmp.Columns(2).Width = 200

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub FillNom()

        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = String.Empty
        SQL = "SELECT IDNomina as ID, Fecha, MontoBruto as 'Monto Bruto', MontoNeto as 'Monto Neto', CantidadEmpleados as Empleados FROM Nomina"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataNomi)

                dgvConsNomi.DataSource = dataNomi

                dgvConsNomi.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillPres()

        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = String.Empty
        SQL = "SELECT IDPrestamo as ID, IDEmpleado as 'ID Empleado', MontoInicial as Monto, Fecha, MontoDescuento as Descuento, FormaDescuento as Recurrencia, Status FROM Prestamos"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataPres)

                dgvConsPres.DataSource = dataPres

                dgvConsPres.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillGast()

        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = String.Empty
        SQL = "SELECT IDGasto as ID, IDEmpleado as 'ID Empleado', Monto, Fecha, Concepto, IDUsuario as Creador FROM GastosEmpleados"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataGast)

                Me.dgvConsGast.DataSource = dataGast

                Me.dgvConsGast.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillAmon()

        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = "SELECT IDAmonestacion as ID, TipoAmonestacion as Tipo, Descripcion, IDUsuario as Creador FROM Amonestaciones"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataAmon)

                dgvConsAmon.DataSource = dataAmon

                dgvConsAmon.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillHora()

        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

        myCommand.Connection = conn
        SQL = "SELECT IDControlHorario as ID, IDEmpleado as 'ID Empleado', Fecha, Hora FROM ControlHorario"

        Try
            conn.Open()

            Try
                myCommand.Connection = conn
                myCommand.CommandText = SQL

                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
                myAdapter.Fill(dataHora)

                dgvConsHora.DataSource = dataHora

                dgvConsHora.Columns(0).Width = 30

            Catch myerror As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
            End Try
        Catch myerror As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show("Ocurrió un error conectando a la base de datos: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close()
        End Try
        dgvConsHora.Refresh()
    End Sub


    Private Sub frmMantenimiento_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FillEmps()
        FillNom()
        FillPres()
        FillHora()
        FillGast()
        FillAmon()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could be going abit overboard with the DRY principle.  When you consider  [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx), one connection object is all you will need.  If the each table resides on a different DB, all you need it 8 different connection strings and the pooling will take care of the each of the connections.  And unless you have a framework in place that could dynamically create you SQL queries for you, you will definately need an SQL select string per Datagrid.  Hope you aren't using the VS wizards to do this.

```
Public Sub FillEmps() 

    myCommand.Connection = conn 
    SQL = "SELECT IDEmpleado as ID, Nombre, Cargo FROM Empleados" 

    Try 
       myCommand.Connection = conn 
       myCommand.CommandText = SQL 

       myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand 
       myAdapter.Fill(dataEmp) 

       dgvConsEmp.DataSource = dataEmp 

       dgvConsEmp.Columns(0).Width = 30 
       dgvConsEmp.Columns(1).Width = 200 
       dgvConsEmp.Columns(2).Width = 200 

    Catch myerror As MySqlException 
        MsgBox("Ocurrió un error leyendo la base de datos: " & myerror.Message) 
    End Try 
End Sub 


Private Sub frmMantenimiento_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")

    Try
        conn.Open()

        FillEmps() 
        FillNom() 
        FillPres() 
        FillHora() 
        FillGast() 
        FillAmon() 
    Catch
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close() 
    Finally
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Close() 
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Not using Wizards, I have a connectiong string and 8 DataTables to fill the Datagrids, 1 MySQLCommand and 1 MySQLAdapter. I've populated them with a query and the filling the corresponding DataTable, the problem is I don't know why it is populating only 3 of my Datagridviews. Just added my code above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well first, I assume you ommitted two of the eight routines that that fill your data grids.  Are there any exceptions being trown?  Did you check MySQL error log?  Are you hitting your connection limit?  Which tables are failing to fill?

Comment: No exceptions, my form load but only populate the first 3 FillX() on the load. Is there another way that i can try?

Comment: Instead of opening and closing the connection for each fill, why don't you let the `frmMantenimiento_Load` handle open and closing the connection instead of each fill sub procedure.

Comment: BTW, this is called refactoring ;).

Comment: Did it, thank you for that, it is a much better code. But my problem persist, I just realized that if i load FillGast() and FillHora() each one alone, the Datagridviews get populated, but only if they are each one loading alone. The other ones (FillEmps(), FillAmon(), FillNom(), FillPres()) can get the Datagridviews populated together with no problems. I can't find why those 2 can't load together with the another 4 :S

Comment: Try taking the `dgvConsHora.Refresh()` statement out the `FillHora()' subroutine.